# Row_Number Invalid Column name in where clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, row-number

Below I have a stored procedure that should only show records between two numbers based on the parameters @From and @To. However when I run this I get an error of invalid column name RecordID. I want to be able to run this procedure and the RecordID column adapt depending on what the where clause is which I believe this code will do but it won't run.

```
 SELECT Alerts.*, ClaimRepairs.ClaimID,ClaimRepairs.VehicleRegistration,ClaimRepairs.RepairerName, ClaimRepairs.Status,Claims.HasComplaint,
     CASE 
        WHEN Deployments.DeploymentDate IS NOT NULL AND ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate IS NOT NULL 
        THEN datediff(dd, Deployments.DeploymentDate, ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate) - (datediff(wk, Deployments.DeploymentDate, ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate) * 2) -
            case
                when datepart(dw, Deployments.DeploymentDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
            case 
                when datepart(dw, ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end
        WHEN Deployments.DeploymentDate IS NOT NULL AND ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate IS NULL
        THEN datediff(dd, Deployments.DeploymentDate,GETDATE()) - (datediff(wk, Deployments.DeploymentDate, GETDATE()) * 2) -
            case 
                when datepart(dw, Deployments.DeploymentDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
            case
                when datepart(dw, GETDATE()) = 1 then 1 else 0 end
        WHEN MRD.DeploymentDate IS NOT NULL AND ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate IS NOT NULL
            THEN datediff(dd, MRD.DeploymentDate, ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate) - (datediff(wk, MRD.DeploymentDate, ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate) * 2) -
            case
                when datepart(dw, MRD.DeploymentDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
            case 
                when datepart(dw, ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end
            WHEN MRD.DeploymentDate IS NOT NULL AND ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate IS NULL
        THEN datediff(dd, MRD.DeploymentDate,GETDATE()) - (datediff(wk, MRD.DeploymentDate, GETDATE()) * 2) -
            case 
                when datepart(dw, MRD.DeploymentDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
            case
                when datepart(dw, GETDATE()) = 1 then 1 else 0 end
     END AS DaysBetweenDeploymentDateOnSite,
     CASE 
        WHEN ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate IS NOT NULL AND ClaimRepairs.WorkStartedDate IS NOT NULL
        THEN datediff(dd, ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate, ClaimRepairs.WorkStartedDate) - (datediff(wk,ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate, ClaimRepairs.WorkStartedDate) * 2) -
            case
                 when datepart(dw, ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
            case
                 when datepart(dw, ClaimRepairs.WorkStartedDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end
        WHEN ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate IS NOT NULL AND ClaimRepairs.WorkStartedDate IS NULL
        THEN datediff(dd, ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate, GETDATE()) - (datediff(wk,ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate, GETDATE()) * 2) -
            case
                 when datepart(dw, ClaimRepairs.ConfirmedOnSiteDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
            case
                 when datepart(dw, GETDATE()) = 1 then 1 else 0 end
     END AS DaysBetweenOnSiteAndDateStarted,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Alerts.AlertID DESC) AS RecordID
    FROM ALERTS
    INNER JOIN ClaimRepairs ON Alerts.ClaimRepairID = ClaimRepairs.ClaimRepairID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Claims ON ClaimRepairs.ClaimID = Claims.ClaimID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN IDSSearches ON Claims.ClaimID = IDSSearches.ClaimID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Deployments ON IDSSearches.DeploymentID = Deployments.DeploymentID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ManufacturerRepairerDeployments MRD ON IDSSearches.ManufacturerRepairerDeploymentID = MRD.ManufacturerRepairerDeploymentID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ManufacturerApprovedRepairers MAR ON MRD.ApprovedRepairerID = MAR.ApprovedRepairerId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SiteProfiles ON Deployments.SiteProfileID = SiteProfiles.SiteProfileID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Actions ON Alerts.AlertID = Actions.AlertID  
    WHERE RecordID >= ''' +  convert(nvarchar(50), @From) + ''' AND RecordID < ''' +  convert(nvarchar(50), @To) + ''' AND Alerts.AlertType != 1 AND Alerts.AlertType != 2 AND Alerts.AlertType != 3  AND (Alerts.Status = 0 AND Alerts.FollowUpDate <= GETDATE() OR Alerts.Status = 0 AND Alerts.FollowUpDate IS NULL)'

IF (@WorkProviderCode != '')
BEGIN
    SET @SQL_STATEMENT = @SQL_STATEMENT + ' AND (ClaimRepairs.WorkProviderCode LIKE ''' + @WorkProviderCode + ''' OR Claims.WorkProviderCode LIKE ''' + @WorkProviderCode + ''')'
END
```

Previously I had the following Row_Number count which worked however, I need the where clause to match the where clause at the bottom of the procedure dynamically.

```
FROM (SELECT Alerts.*,
         (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Alerts.AlertID DESC)) AS RecordID
    FROM Alerts 
    WHERE Alerts.AlertType != 1 AND Alerts.AlertType != 2 AND Alerts.AlertType != 3  AND (Alerts.Status = 0 AND Alerts.FollowUpDate <= GETDATE() OR Alerts.Status = 0 AND Alerts.FollowUpDate IS NULL)
   ) AS A
```

Comment: can you check which table that has the column RecordID? Does it really exists in any of the tables?

Comment: You can't base your `where` clause on columns generated on the `select` clause of the same query.  
What you can do is use a common table expression or a derived query, and use the `where` clause on the `RecordId` column on that.

Comment: Also, for your future questions - Please try to minimize the code. All the cases and left joins are not relevant to the current question. We don't need to see the code you are actually using, just a minimal example that can reproduce the problem. For more information, read [mcve].

Comment: You need to build a sub query to generate the RecordID for you.

Answer (score 2):

As your were told in comments already, you cannot use the name of an aliased column in the `WHERE` clause. The common way to solve this is a common table expression (cte):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT ...
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...) AS RecordID --aliased column
    Your query here without the WHERE-clause
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE RecordID >= ...
```

Btw: Your code seems to be part of a dynamically built statement and is not valid the way you are showing it. From the part I can see there is no real reason for this approach...

In rare situations (with a huge lot of rows) this might be necessary for performance reasons, but I doubt this here...